# Cauchy Schwarz manipulation

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to manipulate the upper bound below using Cauchy Schwarz, so that the norm of the vector a, $||a||$, appears on the right hand side ($a_i$ itself is a scalar, $a$ is the vector). Which I think is possible with some manipulations, but I can not see it at the moment. I have the following:

$$ \sum_i a_i ^2 b^2_{ij} \leq \left(\sum_i (a_i^2)^2 \sum_i (b^2_{ij})^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

I'd like to have a bound of $||a||^2 $ or $||a||$ on the right hand side, where I'm less concerned about the expression/bound involving $b_{ij}$.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about $(\max_i b_{ij}^{2} )\|a\|^{2}$?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. Is there another possibility on the bound involving the norm of a? Although your answer is definitely a solution, so I can modify my question and title a bit if needed.